# Virtualbox centos no eth0

Tags: virtualbox, centos6

just installed a fresh centos-minimal and i can not get bridged network to work or any of the networks not even in host-only mode. when you run ifconfig there is no eth0 only a lo,

also when you cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR="08:00:27:FE:D5:10"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="no"
```

Comment: Did you try using `ifconfig -a` instead of `ifconfig`? The former will display information about adapters that aren't in the 'UP' state.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As cpuguru said, you need to config the network. So login on your centos and execute:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

As Chris R explained, you should edit the contents of that file to end up having this:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR=MAC Address*System MAC*
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
```

Then save (escape :wq INTRO) and then reboot:

```
reboot
```

Comment: If you have cloned a VM or otherwise changed the MAC you may need to delete `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` ... please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with CentOS on Hyper-V the other day.

The solution seemed to be to fire up a terminal, su to root and run 'system-config-network' to enable CentOS to use the virtual nic.

Comment: retuned Command not found.

Comment: This is where I found the command:
http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-network-config.html

Comment: I am using centos 6 i got eth0 to show in ifconfig but it has no IPs or anything.

Comment: Try changing your ifcfg-eth0 script parameter from ONBOOT="no" to ONBOOT="yes"

Comment: Thank you had to change my ifcfg-eth0 script to DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR=MAC Address*System MAC*
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"

Comment: Yay! I helped answer a Linux question (linux newb that I am ;?)

Answer (score 0):

1. bridged adapter = connect with already connected internet device
2. nat

and run..